# XLRD, check if one sheet doesn't exist else check for another

Tags: python, xlrd

Trying to read in an series of xls files. They aren't formatted in a uniform manner. Sometimes the sheets exist, sometimes they don't. Sometimes they have one name, sometimes another. It's an imperfect world.

Some code I've tried to check for the sheet name:

```py
import xlrd

wb=xlrd.open_workbook(r'C:\sample.xls')

class Workbook_Reading:

    def __init__(self, wb):
        self.wb = wb
        self.history = None

    def purch_hist(self):
        if self.wb.sheet_loaded('Purchase History') is True:
            purchase_history = wb.sheet_by_name('Purchase History')
            self.history = purchase_history
        elif self.wb.sheet_loaded('Previous Purchases') is True:
            purchase_history = wb.sheet_by_name('Previous Purchases')
            self.history = purchase_history
        else:
            pass
```

I keep getting an error: `xlrd.bffh.XLRDError: No Sheet Named <'Purchase History'>`. I am testing this one a wb that I know specifically doesn't have the first condition (purchase history sheet), but has the other (previous purchases sheet). What did I do wrong?

Comment: Even after you edited your original post `self.wb` would raise `AttributeError: 'Workbook_Reading' object has no attribute 'wb'`, because your class has no wb attribute. i.e. this is not the actual code if you get the `xlrd.bffh.XLRDError: No Sheet Named <'Purchase History'>` as you claim

Comment: Also `c:sample.xls` has missing backlash and will raise FileNotFoundError in the first place

Comment: how about creating a list of sheetnames and then iterating them with the sheet_by_name() function in a try/catch block.

Comment: sorry, I was very quickly making sample code. it does have a self.wb and a C:\. I'll edit those in but @Jabb I'll try doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help

```
import xlrd

class Workbook_Reading:

    def __init__(self, wb):
        self.history = None
        self.desiredSheetNames = ['Purchase History', 'Previous Purchases']
        self.availableSheetNames = []
        self.wb = xlrd.open_workbook(r'C:\\sample.xls')
        self.set_available_sheets()

    def set_available_sheets(self):
        for sheetName in self.desiredSheetNames:
            try:
                sheet = self.wb.sheet_by_name(sheetName)
                self.availableSheetNames.append(sheetName)
            except:
                pass

    def purch_hist(self):
        if 'Purchase History' in self.availableSheetNames:
            purchase_history = wb.sheet_by_name('Purchase History')
            self.history = purchase_history
        elif 'Previous Purchases') in self.availableSheetNames:
            purchase_history = wb.sheet_by_name('Previous Purchases')
            self.history = purchase_history
        else:
            pass
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Jabb in his initial comment, the right way to go is try/except. His example though is bit [unnecessary] overcomplicated, e.g. no need to create a method to set available sheets, you can simply use `book.sheet_names()` all the same (to check if sheet with given name exists). But as I said, it's not even necessary to check using if/elif/else block, just use try/except.

```
import xlrd

file_name = r'some_path\some_file.xls' # replace with your file

class Workbook_Reader:
    def __init__(self, wb, lookup_sheets=('Purchase History', 'Previous Purchases')):
        self.wb = xlrd.open_workbook(wb)
        self.lookup_sheets = lookup_sheets

    @property
    def purchase_history(self): # this property will return the respective sheet or None
        for sheet_name in self.lookup_sheets:
            try:
                return self.wb.sheet_by_name(sheet_name)
            except xlrd.biffh.XLRDError:
                pass

foo = Workbook_Reader(file_name)
for row in foo.purchase_history.get_rows():
    for cl in row:
        print(cl.value)
```

Note that iterating over lookup_sheets, `first seen wins`